# Printing Tex Stack Exchange Questions

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if there is an easy way on this website to print the solutions to questions presented by other users for reference purposes? And is there like a database with answered questions readily available other than by search?

Comment: You are best if you ask one question be question I would suggest that you move the second question to a new question. For printing your question is similar too (maybe even a duplicate of) http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-to-print-out-a-full-q-a-entry-or-forward-it-outside-the-stackexchange-site

Comment: Also see [Printable version of questions/answers or entire discussion](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1680/5764) suggesting the same, with a similar answer.

Comment: Why can't a link like the "link edit close delete flag" be added to facilitate the printer. I am not always on the net so reference would help a lot and printing it directly for the question page minimizes the search for extra apps or softwares. Just a suggestions

Comment: I had seen a video of how to get really great printout of TeX.SE questions, that for some reason I think @PauloCereda had posted.

Comment: See [printing tex sx threads](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/printing-tex-sx-threads/)

Answer (score 3):

You need [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/), a [community project](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) ran on Google Apps.

The interface should be self-explanatory, and you get a printer-friendly HTML of the question that you can print to paper or to an electronic format from your browser. See how the Cthulhu question [looks like](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=29402&service=tex.stackexchange):

[image]

Images and links are preserved as they are, as is code formatting. One might argue that the spacing makes the text hard to read (at least on my 22'' monitor), but not something a smattering of CSS magic can't cure.