# Referencing and saving Stack Exchange Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion

When I find an answer to a question I would like to be able to save the text of the question and answer(s) and also the code in text format so that I can study and modify it for my own use. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Similarly I would like to be able to go back to a Q & A by, e.g., a simple designation (numbers/letters etc). Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Cut and paste the code into a file somewhere, or mark the post with a star so that you can find it again more easily...

Comment: maybe helpful: https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite

Comment: @PauloCereda could help, I think.

Comment: Related/duplicate(s): [Printing TeX Stack Exchange questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2245/5764); [Printable version of questions/answers or entire discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1680/5764); [How to print out a full Q/A entry? Or forward it outside the Stack Exchange site?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/825/5764)